# Python DictReader - Skipping rows with missing columns?

Tags: python, csv

I have a Excel .CSV file I'm attempting to read in with DictReader.

All seems to be well, except it seems to omit rows, specifically those with missing columns.

Our input looks like:

```
mail,givenName,sn,lorem,ipsum,dolor,telephoneNumber
ian.bay@blah.com,ian,bay,3424,8403,2535,+65(2)34523534545
mike.gibson@blah.com,mike,gibson,3424,8403,2535,+65(2)34523534545
ross.martin@blah.com,ross,martin,,,,+65(2)34523534545
david.connor@blah.com,david,connor,,,,+65(2)34523534545
chris.call@blah.com,chris,call,3424,8403,2535,+65(2)34523534545
```

So some of the rows have missing lorem/ipsum/dolor columns, and it's just a string of commas for those.

We're reading it in with:

```
def read_gd_dump(input_file="blah 20100423.csv"):
    gd_extract = csv.DictReader(open('blah 20100423.csv'), restval='missing', dialect='excel')
    return dict([(row['something'], row) for row in gd_extract])
```

And I checked that "something" (the key for our dict) isn't one of the missing columns, I had originally suspected it might be that. It's one of the columns after that.

However, DictReader seems to completely skip over the rows. I tried setting restval to something, didn't seem to make any difference. I can't seem to find anything in Python's CSV docs (http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html) that would explain this behaviour, but I may have misread something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't reproduce your problem -- when I save that data and then assign `list(gd_extract)`, I see:

```
[{'telephoneNumber': '+65(2)34523534545', 'ipsum': '8403', 'sn': 'bay', 'dolor': '2535', 'mail': 'ian.bay@blah.com', 'givenName': 'ian', 'lorem': '3424'}, {'telephoneNumber': '+65(2)34523534545', 'ipsum': '8403', 'sn': 'gibson', 'dolor': '2535', 'mail': 'mike.gibson@blah.com', 'givenName': 'mike', 'lorem': '3424'}, {'telephoneNumber': '+65(2)34523534545', 'ipsum': '', 'sn': 'martin', 'dolor': '', 'mail': 'ross.martin@blah.com', 'givenName': 'ross', 'lorem': ''}, {'telephoneNumber': '+65(2)34523534545', 'ipsum': '', 'sn': 'connor', 'dolor': '', 'mail': 'david.connor@blah.com', 'givenName': 'david', 'lorem': ''}, {'telephoneNumber': '+65(2)34523534545', 'ipsum': '8403', 'sn': 'call', 'dolor': '2535', 'mail': 'chris.call@blah.com', 'givenName': 'chris', 'lorem': '3424'}]
```

five dicts, including those with missing `ipsum` etc.  I fear that in your laudable attempt at simplifying the problem you've simplified it excessively, so that your bug has gone away.

If you have duplicates in column `something` (can't check, since you don't **have** that column in your sample data) that would of course explain the "apparently missing" rows -- they're not missing from the csv reader's returned stream, they get "overwritten" in the dict you're returning.  Could that be the issue?

Comment: Woah, *the* Alex Materlli *grins*. Hi =). Are you ever updating Python in a Nutshell, btw?

Yeah, I simplified it both to make it easier to read, and also for privacy/compliance reasons (the place I work for is rather...stringent).

Turns out you were right, see Edit above.

Comment: @victor, I was scheduled to update the Nutshell but I found out I can't do a really great job unless I'm really using the Python release I'm supposed to update the Nutshell to -- I mean in real life as opposed to playing around with it and answering SO questions;-). We're soon upgrading at work so that should eventually change!

Comment: Alex, aha, looking forward to it =). You should have both a vote and a tick (that's what I did on my end). Check again?
Also, I posted a followup question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2901872/python-checking-for-membership-inside-nested-dict I think it has a fairly easy solution, I'm probably just a bit sleep-deprived/retarded right now. Thanks.

Comment: @victor, checked at the time, I didn't, when I found that changed I fixed my comment.  I'd love to help on your other Q but I'm getting pretty sleep-deprived too and I find it just too hard to grasp -- if you edited that Q to add a toy example of what the employees dict may look like and what output you want in a couple examples of your target function that would probably help a lot (but I'm going to sleep soon anyway now;-).

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure it's some crazy hour wherever you are =). Thanks for your help. And I followed your advice, and added some dict samples to my other question. Hopefully it'll be a little clearer for whoevers reading it.

Answer (score 0):

This may be nothing to do with your problem, and Alex's analysis is quite plausible given the lack of information, but you should **ALWAYS** open a csv file with `"rb"` or `"wb"` mode (assuming Python 2.X). If you don't, you run the risk of various mysterious happenings. **A csv file is not a text file, it's a BINARY file.**

In any case, please edit your question to show:
(1) (a) a sample file (b) a script (c) output -- which together demonstrate the alleged problem
(2) what version of Python you are running
(3) what OS

Update: For Python 3.X, do as [the blessed manual](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/csv.html#module-contents) says: """If `csvfile` is a file object, it should be opened with `newline=''`. Although this advice is included only with `csv.reader`, it applies equally to `csv.writer`, `csv.DictReader`, and `csv.DictWriter`.

Comment: I'm using Python 3.x - sorry, I should have stated that. Does that change your advice regarding rb/wb?